# How to check err type returned from function(strconv.Atoi)

Tags: go, strconv

I have the following basic code that tests `strconv.Atoi()`:

```golang
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "strconv"
)

func main() {

        var a int
        var b string
        var err Error

        b = "32"

        a,err = strconv.Atoi(b)

        fmt.Println(a)
        fmt.Println(err)

}
```

I want to handle if there was an Error in `strconv.Atoi()`, and specifically if the error was due to syntax or range, conditions that `strconv.Atoi()` can provide. To do that I have tried this:

```golang
package main

import (
        "os"
        "fmt"
        "strconv"
)

func main() {

        var a int
        var b string
        var err error

        b = "32"

        a,err = strconv.Atoi(b)

        if(err.Err == ErrSyntax) {
                fmt.Println("ERROR")
                os.Exit(1)
        }

        fmt.Println(a)
        fmt.Println(err)

}
```

And I get this as result:

```
% go build test.go
# command-line-arguments
./test.go:19:8: err.Err undefined (type error has no field or method Err)
./test.go:19:16: undefined: ErrSyntax
```

I would like to understand how to process the two errors `Atoi` can return (`ErrSyntax`, `ErrRange`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`errors`](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/) package ([Working with Errors in Go 1.13](https://blog.golang.org/go1.13-errors)):

```
if errors.Is(err, strconv.ErrSyntax) {
    fmt.Println("syntax error")
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

Comment: This seems easier to read than the answer using `err.(*strconv.NumError).Err == strconv.ErrSyntax`

Comment: And more safe  `err.(*strconv.NumError).Err` may produce a `panic` when you use an `api` which return `error` interface. Example:  `panic: interface conversion: error is *errors.errorString, not *strconv.NumError` ➡️ tried to cast one `type` to other one. You always have to check the casting (`err, ok := err.(*strconv.NumError); ok {...}`).

Answer (score 3):

Package docs for a package show the names without the package qualifier, to use them from elsewhere, you have to qualify them. So try `strconv.ErrSyntax`.

But that won't quite help, because there's no `.Err` member of a generic error interface. To check that, you'd have to know that the returned error is in fact a `strconv.*NumError`. Which it should be, according to the docs.

https://play.golang.org/p/UKL6kKDqSx4

```
    if err != nil && err.(*strconv.NumError).Err == strconv.ErrSyntax {
        fmt.Println("syntax error")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
```